# Retrieve view in dialog

Tags: kotlin, findviewbyid

I'm trying to manipulate views inside a dialog, but the only way I can retrieve the views is in the Java old fashioned way, like this:

```
 class MyDialog: DialogFragment() {
        override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
            val alert = AlertDialog.Builder(context!!)
            val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity)
            val view = inflater?.inflate(R.layout.pg_dialog, null)
            with(alert) {
                setView(view)
                setNeutralButton(R.string.scambio_back, DialogInterface.OnClickListener({ _: DialogInterface, _: Int -> dialog.dismiss() }))
            }
            view?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.dialog_name)?.text = person.name
            view?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.dialog_surname)?.text = person.surname

            return alert.create()
        }
    }
```

Do you know any way to retrieve inner views in Kotlin, avoiding findViewById?

[Edit] Here's the build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.project.persons"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'

    // Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'

    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.2'

    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.30.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Are you using Kotlin Android Extensions for View lookups elsewhere? Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: I use kotlin extensions, yes

Comment: see the answer from my another related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52965122/5518220

Answer (score 3):

In this case, when you're not in a `Fragment` or an `Activity`, but have a `View` reference that you want to search for children with a given ID, you can use Kotlin Android Extensions with this syntax:

```
view.dialog_name.text = person.name
view.dialog_surname.text = person.surname
```

As with always when using Extensions, make sure you have the correct imports.

Comment: I do use Extensions, but view.dialog_name cannot be found, it gives me an unresolved reference over dialog_name, though importing kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.pg_dialog.*

Comment: Can you post your `build.gradle` file? Perhaps it's not configured correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just illustrating a little bit more with an example on how to get the view: ```val alertDialog = alertDialogBuilderUserInput.create()
alertDialog.show()
alertDialog.etName.setText("a")```

Answer (score -1):

Since your question is a little bit unclear I'd say you refer to do something like this :

Do import `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions` in your `build.gradle`

Then you have to import this in your `Activity`

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_pg_dialog.*
```

If you for example have a `TextView` with an id `test` you could do this:

```
test.setText("test text!!")
```

References :

[Documentation Kotlin Android Extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html)

[Example Kotlin Android Extendions](https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-android-extensions/)

Comment: Your solution does compile, but dialog_name is null and throws IllegalStateException. I imported kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.pg_dialog.* and the line throwing exception is dialog_name.text = person.name