# DialogFragment with negative button

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I want to make an About dialog in my app, and I want it to have the default dialog's button, and I decided to use DialogFragment, so I made it like this

```
public class AboutDialog extends DialogFragment {

public AboutDialog() {
    // Empty constructor for fragment
}

@Override
@NonNull
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("About");
    builder.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dismiss();
        }
    });
    return builder.create();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.about_dialog, container);
    getDialog().setTitle(getString(R.string.action_about));
    return rootView;
}
```

}

then call it from the Activity like this

```
AboutDialog about = new AboutDialog();
        about.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
```

and then I get this error

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you please post your Activity code too.

Comment: what exactly from Activity? This is being called in onOptionsItemSelected

Comment: oncreate code of your activity

Comment: why is that needed? the problem is in the DialogFragment

Comment: @Pravin tried it, but still crashes with the same error

Comment: can you go through this SO question related to same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508185/problem-inflating-custom-view-for-alertdialog-in-dialogfragment DialogFragment requestFeature() problem

Comment: @Pravin nope, didnt solved my problem

Comment: Is it is applicable for you to use 'builder.setView(your_view);' instead of using onCreateView(). If yes then setview before setting Title to Dialog

Comment: ahhh yes, now it works, give me an answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.about_dialog, null));
    builder.setMessage("Test")
           .setPositiveButton("fire", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // User cancelled the dialog
               }
           });
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();
}

remove your onCreateView
```