# What is lifecycle of DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment, appcompatdialogfragment

I could not find proper lifecycle of `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment` by searching on Google. I need this for some implementation. As we know `DialogFragment` has some methods same like `Dialog`.

`DialogFragment` extends `Fragment` so its lifecycle is same as `Fragment`. But what about other methods of `DialogFragment`?

Here is `Fragment` lifecycle. Can one provide for `DialogFragment`?

[image]

Comment: Here you go official documentation .https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment#Lifecycle

Comment: this may help you https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment#Lifecycle

Comment: @NileshRathod & Umair, I checked this also before posting question. Please let me know, do you get a satisfying answer from this documentation?

Comment: @Khemraj dialogFragment's life cycle is similar to fragment.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`DialogFragment` life cycle is similar to the life cycle of **`fragment:`**. To test yourself put logs in each of the `overrided` methods of *`dialogFragment`* and then run your code you will understand the working of `dialogFragment`.

```
onAttach
onCreate
onCreateDialog
onCreateView
onActivityCreated
onStart
onResume
```

And as far as finishing or destroying dialogFragment is concerned the lifeCycle is as follows:

```
onPause
onStop
onDestroyView
onDestroy
onDetach
```

Also I believe this method will also help you know the `lifecycle` :

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Lifecycle getLifecycle() {
    return super.getLifecycle();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I could also check lifecycle by creating logs, but I posted question. Because SO should be a good collection of questions. You should also add onStop, onDestroy etc. also to make answer good.

Comment: @Khemraj yes it should be, dialogFragment just act like a fragment because if you look closely in documentation dialogFragment extends Fragment which implements callbacks. Happy Coding :)

Comment: It is understood, I mentioned in question, that DialogFragment extends Fragment. But I did not know the sequence on onCreateDialog.

Comment: That's not true. `onCreateDialog` is never guaranteed to be called before `onStart`/`onResume`. Basically it's not part of the "true" lifecycle.

Answer (score 6):

Strange, that if you created an `AlertDialog` in `onCreateDialog()`, didn't call `onCreateView()`, then `onViewCreated()` wouldn't also call.

See [Android DialogFragment onViewCreated not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594992/android-dialogfragment-onviewcreated-not-called) and [OnCreateView not called in a dialogfragment from a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715546/oncreateview-not-called-in-a-dialogfragment-from-a-fragment).

Answer (score 2):

> DialogFragment does various things to keep the fragment's lifecycle
>   driving it, instead of the Dialog. Note that dialogs are generally
>   autonomous entities -- they are their own window, receiving their own
>   input events, and often deciding on their own when to disappear (by
>   receiving a back key event or the user clicking on a button).

Source :
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment#lifecycle