# Where to put viewModel Observers in a dialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-livedata

For fragments it is [advised](https://medium.com/@BladeCoder/architecture-components-pitfalls-part-1-9300dd969808) to put liveData observers in the onActivityCreated method. This works fine for fragments, but when I apply this to a dialogFragment I get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't access the Fragment View's LifecycleOwner when getView() is null i.e., before onCreateView() or after onDestroyView().

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51614834/what-is-lifecycle-of-dialogfragment) I read the lifecycle of the dialogFragment at creation is:

```
onAttach
onCreate
onCreateDialog
onCreateView
onActivityCreated
onStart
onResume
```

So putting the observers in onActivityCreated should be fine as it is after onCreateView or onCreateDialog. I use the latter as I use a Alertdialog with my own layout.

This is the code for my observer:

```
mScheduleViewModel.getTeachers().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<String>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<String> strings) {
            mStringList = strings;
            aclInputvalue.setThreshold(2);
            aclAdapter.setList(strings);
            aclAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            ....
}
```

This code pattern works fine in a fragment but not in a dialogFragment. There I have to set the lifecycleOwner to 'this'.

So why do I get the error?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: I used 'this' for the lifecycleOwner.

Comment: @KvdLingen This is the correct way as mentioned in docs (https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/dialogs#lifecycle)

Answer (score 6):

Update: See Farid's link below, this answer is probably not recommended.

You can use `ViewModels` in a `DialogFragment` when you are overriding `onCreateDialog` by doing this:

1. When you inflate your custom view in `onCreateDialog`, store a reference to it as a variable in your `DialogFragment`.
2. Override `onCreateView` and simply return your saved custom view.
3. Set the view to null in `onDestroyView` exactly like this (otherwise Leak Canary reported memory leaks)

```
    override fun onDestroyView() {
        myView = null
        super.onDestroyView()
    }
```

Then, the dialog behaves more like a normal fragment and you can observe your `ViewModel` in `onCreateView`, `onViewCreated` or `onActivityCreated` as you please.

Comment: A minor nitpick - I don't believe DialogFragment ever calls onViewCreated()

Comment: `androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment` does definitely call `onViewCreated`.

Comment: It will call `onViewCreated` if you inflated a Layout in `onCreateView`. If you only provide the Dialog in `onCreateDialog` it will not invoke `onViewCreated`, since `onCreateView` returned `null` before.

Comment: @isabsent It definitely doesn't call `onViewCreated` if `onCreateDialog` is overridden. Now, can you please tell us where that "definitely" comes from?!

Comment: Passing `this` is the correct way as mentioned here (https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/dialogs#lifecycle) in the highlighted box