# How to show a customized DialogFragment in the activity

Tags: java, android, dialogfragment

I am trying to build an `AlertDialog` and want to show it when the main activity starts. But when the activity starts, an error comes up:

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Window feature must be requested before adding content
```

What I do first is creating an `AlertFragment`:

```
public class AlertFragment extends DialogFragment{

    public static AlertFragment newInstance(){
        return new AlertFragment();
    }

    public AlertFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle SavedInstanceState){

        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, SavedInstanceState);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle SaveInstanceState){

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Dialog)).setMessage("Alert Dialog").setPositiveButton("Set", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Positive", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Negative", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).create();
    }
}
```

The following is the main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AlertFragment AF = AlertFragment.newInstance();
        AF.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Dialog");
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me where the problem lies?

Comment: check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508185/problem-inflating-custom-view-for-alertdialog-in-dialogfragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your AlertFragment remove oncreateview and run

```
public class AlertFragment extends DialogFragment{

public static AlertFragment newInstance(){
    return new AlertFragment(); }

public AlertFragment(){}



@Override 
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle SaveInstanceState){

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Dialog)).setMessage("Alert Dialog").setPositiveButton("Set", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Positive", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Negative", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }).create(); 
} 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use show in place of create in your code like following:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle SaveInstanceState){ 

return new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Dialog)).setMessage("Alert Dialog").setPositiveButton("Set", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Positive", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Negative", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}).show();
```